# Flutter Firebase Auth Change Password and Email

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app with Flutter and Firebase
I want to edit user profile information...
When I update the name, it works fine, but when updating the email or password, it is updated only in the Fire store, not in Firebase Authentication. How do I solve this problem ? Because when the user updates his email, he cannot log in to the account with the new email because it did not update in Firebase Authentication.
I read in the documentation that it is necessary to re-authenticate and I tried it but i get this error:

```
I/FirebaseAuth(22578): Logging in as ma@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  (22578): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/EGL_emulation(22578): app_time_stats: avg=35.73ms min=5.42ms max=436.74ms count=22
D/FirebaseAuth(22578): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth(22578): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(22578): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /FirstPage
[GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /EditProfile
[GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /Homepage
I/flutter (22578): [firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
E/flutter (22578): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type
```

edit_profile.dart:

```
class EditProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(ProfileController());
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 15),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: controller.getUserData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  UserModel userData = snapshot.data as UserModel;

                  //controllers to update values
                  final email = TextEditingController(text: userData.email);
                  final password =
                      TextEditingController(text: userData.password);
                  final name = TextEditingController(text: userData.name);

                  return Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Text(
                            "user name",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: AppColor.TertiaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomTextFormField(
                          controller: name,
                          validator: (value) {},
                          ispasswordType: false,
                          hasIcon: false,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 5),
                          child: Text(
                            "email",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: AppColor.TertiaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomTextFormField(
                          controller: email,
                          validator: (value) {},
                          ispasswordType: false,
                          hasIcon: false,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 5),
                          child: Text(
                            "password",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: AppColor.TertiaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomTextFormField(
                          ispasswordType: true,
                          hasIcon: false,
                          controller: password,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null) {
                              print("error");
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        CustomButton(
                          text: "save",
                          onPressed: () async {
                            final user = UserModel(
                                uid: userData.uid,
                                email: email.text.trim(),
                                name: name.text.trim(),
                                password: password.text.trim());
                            await controller.updateUserData(
                                user, password.text);
                            Get.to(() => Profile());
                          },
                          buttonColor: AppColor.primaryColor,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                } else {
                  return Text(snapshot.toString());
                  
                }
              } else {
                return Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

profile_controller.dart:

```
class ProfileController extends GetxController {
  static ProfileController get instance => Get.find();

  final _user_controller = Get.put(UserController());

  //fetch user information from database
  getUserData() {
    final email = _auth_controller.firebaseUser.value?.email;
    if (email != null) {
      return _user_controller.getUserDetails(email);
    } else {
      Get.snackbar('error', '...'); 
    }
  }

  //update user information
  updateUserData(UserModel user, String oldPassword) async {
    await _user_controller.updateUserRecord(user, oldPassword);
   
  }
}
```

user_controller.dart:

```
// this class to perform database user opreations
class UserController extends GetxController {
  static UserController get instance => Get.find();
  //
  final _auth_controller = Get.put(AuthController());
  final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  /// - fetch user data
  Future<UserModel> getUserDetails(String email) async {
    final snapshot = await _db
        .collection('users')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
        .get(); // all data
    //convert snapshot to single record
    final userData = snapshot.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(e)).single;
    return userData;
  }

  /// - update user data
  Future<void> updateUserRecord(UserModel user, String oldPassword) async {
    //reference: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/
    var current_user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    //// Create a credential
    AuthCredential credential =
        EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: user.email, password: oldPassword);

    // Reauthenticate
    await current_user!
        .reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
        .then((value) async =>
            {await _db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).update(user.toJson())})
        .catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
  }
}
```

I read in the documentation that it is necessary to re-authenticate and I tried it but i get error, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to call  `await current_user.updateEmail(user.email)` before the re-authentication